# Can I use an Icon by passing a string in a text widget like Html? flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a text which contains an icon. I found out Icon has a kind of code inside. Is it possible to get an icon by passing the code in a text? like Html does.
Or should I use textspan and richtext?

```
 static const IconData logout = IconData(0xe848, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
```

this is icons.dart in flutter

```
<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="&#xf002;" />
```

In Html.

I would like to get a material icon by using the code in icons.dart.
I think if there is a way to implement an icon in text widget. Its gonna be an easier way than to use richtext.

Iconbutton may work but my text is in already inkwell widget(the container widget is wrapped with an inkwell). I have some memos which contain tags. And I would like to show tags with an icon before getting in content screen.
So like this `Text(icon + memo.tags.join(icon))`
I am trying to add the text in the column.

```
Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 120,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    setImage(memo.imageByte),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              memo.title == null ? "" : memo.title,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              memo.content == null ? "" : memo.content,
                              maxLines: 4,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              memo.editTime.split('.')[0],
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: better you use icon button it will be easy to implement

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use named constructors for creating different types of buttons with icons. For instance

```
    FlatButton.icon(
     onPressed: null, 
     icon:  icon: Icon(Icons.add), 
      label: Text("Submit")
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my text widget is already in a Inkwell. Also, I am trying to get a material icon by passing the IconDate code. Maybe I should write more details.

Comment: dont understand your code please add some more

Comment: I edited. Do you think its possible to do without richtext?